# Kotlin operators in, it, is,

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm

I'm a rookie with Kotlin and I can't differ between these three operators, do they have any relation between them? How's their comparison with Java?

Comment: Have you read the [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html)?

Comment: You may also check the link: [Comparison of Kotlin to Java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/comparison-to-java.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no direct connection between them, other than being 2-letter keywords in Kotlin.

They're used for different things:

- `in` is used to test whether one object is contained within another (syntactic sugar for [`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) in Java):

  ```
  if (someObject in someList) …
  ```

  It's also used when iterating through a collection (where Java just uses `:`):

  ```
  for (item in someList) …
  ```

  And to specify that a type parameter is contravariant (where Java would use `? super`):

  ```
  interface List<out E>
  ```
- `it` is used within a lambda that takes exactly one parameter, to refer to the parameter in a concise way without having to give it a name (with no direct Java equivalent):

  ```
  someList.filter{ it < 10 }
  ```
- `is` is used to test whether an object is of a given type (the same as `instanceof` in Java):

  ```
  if (s is String) …
  ```

As @Adrian says, all the keywords are explained in the [Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html) documentation.

Comment: so Kotlin `is` is similar to Java `instanceof`, and `in` has multiple analogs in Java like colon operator ':' in `for` loop, `Collection::contains` method, [range](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) replacement `if (left <= x && x <= right)` can be replaced with `if (x in left..right)

Comment: Indeed.  Though the range check is merely another example of syntactic sugar for a [`contains()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/contains.html) method.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: `it` is not a keyword. You can freely use it as a name anywhere.

Comment: For contravariant there's `in` in Kotlin, `out` is to specify covariance btw.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Technically,  `it` is a [special identifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#special-identifiers), which means that (like soft keywords) it has special meaning in some contexts, and can be used freely as an identifier in others.